# how to cancel yahoo pdr_override()?

Tags: python, pandas

sometime I got an error when using pandas_datareader to download stock data. so I have to use yf.pdr_override() together with pdr.get_data_yahoo() to make it work.

As code in the below website, I am using yf.pdr_override()
https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override() # <== that's all it takes :-)

# download dataframe
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("SPY", start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30")
```

However, for some index like Case-Shiller-HomeIndex, I have to switch back to use regular pandas datareader, for example,

https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#remote-data-fred

```
caseshill_df = pdr.DataReader('CSUSHPINSA', 'fred', start_date, end_date)
```

if I use yf.pdr_override() already, the above pdr.DataReader will give me error like below.
To solve this, I have to restart the kernel and run the code without using yf.pdr_override(), then it works.

so the question is how to cancel yf.pdr_override() after using it?  Thanks for your help

```
ValueError: time data 'fred' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you could try using `yf.download` to get the SPDR data instead of setting `yf.pdr_override()` that way you can still use the `DataReader` to get the Case-Shiller-HomeIndex data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).